# How to add tags on selected items to jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an app in Rails and I've an input text like this:

```
<input type="text" name="task[value]" id="task_value" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

with jquery functions to select suggest value from dropdown-menu and it works all great. 
My problem is: How can i add some css to selected item? i want to have tag like stackoverflow (with the "x" near the item to delete it).
I'm using the gem `'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'` and i tried a lot of plugins with no results. Maybe i'm not using it in the right way.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple form gem, there is a input_html tag, you can pass any html attribute there, for instance:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'special' } %>
  <%= f.input :password, input_html: { style: "font-size:20px;" } %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, input_html: { value: '1' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form